# Change all option tags to the same value

Tags: python, selenium, loops, dropdown

I am trying get all the rounds to be the same and the best i can do is change the first one. The current code has all the player scorecards open now i just need to be able to select the same round for all of them.

ignore all the imports i was trying a few things, i am extremely new to this

Thank you!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Chrome\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.espn.com/golf/leaderboard?tournamentId=401353233")

xpath_number = 1
while True:
    try:
        element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="fittPageContainer"]/div[3]/div/div/section[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[{xpath_number}]/td[1]')
        xpath_number += 1
        action = ActionChains(driver)
        action.click(element)
        action.perform()
              
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code runs a first loop to open the scorecards, then a second loop to change the round. The command `.send_keys(Keys.DOWN * n)` where n is an integer, press the down arrow n times.

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

number_of_players = 10
round_to_select = 1

for idx,down_arrow in enumerate(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.Table__TD:first-child')):
    if idx < number_of_players:
        down_arrow.click()
        time.sleep(.5)
    else:
        break

if round_to_select < 4:
    for idx,menu in enumerate(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.competitors select[class=dropdown__select]')):
        if idx < number_of_players:
            menu.send_keys(Keys.DOWN * (4-round_to_select))
            time.sleep(.5)
        else:
            break
```

Alternatively to `menu.send_keys(Keys.DOWN * (4-round_to_select))` we can also use `Select` as follows

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

...

if round_to_select < 4:
    for idx,menu in enumerate(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.competitors select[class=dropdown__select]')):
        if idx < number_of_players:
            Select(menu).select_by_visible_text(f'Round {round_to_select}')
            time.sleep(.5)
        else:
            break
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Once i imported the Keys from Selenium, it worked perfectly! I really appreciate the help thank you!

Comment: @TSned3 oh yes i forgot about importing Keys! i'm glad i could help you :)